# JQuery DataTables: Server-Side Search Function Breaking with SQL Error

Tags: laravel, datatables

I have a simple DataTable that I populate with data from a database, specifically from a single view called 'degree_inventory' as opposed to a traditional table. My application is written with Laravel, so I source my data using a route that pulls all the objects that correspond to a model and import them into my table. An additional level of complexity exists because the table has 'child rows', but those are not present by default.

My table:

```html
   <table id="program-table" class="table stripe compact">
     <thead>
         <tr>
             <th>Levels</th>
             <th>CIP Code</th>
             <th>CIP Title</th>
             <th>USF Title</th>
             <th>Degree(s)</th>
             <!-- <th>Activated Term</th>
             <th>Suspended Term</th>
             <th>Discontinued Term</th> -->
         </tr>
     </thead>

     <tbody>
     </tbody>
   </table>
```

My DT declaration looks like:

```js
$('#program-table').DataTable({
      processing: true,
      serverSide: true,
      ajax: "{{ route('serverSide') }}",
      columns: [
          {
            "className":      'details-control',
            "orderable":      false,
            "data":           null,
            "width":          '8%',
            "defaultContent": ''
          },
          { data: 'cip', width: '10%'},
          { data: 'cip_title' },
          { data: 'item_name' },
          { data: 'degree_name_list' }
      ],
      pageLength: 25,
      searching: true,
      paging: true,
      fixedHeader: true, //plugin not working
      "order": [[ 1, "asc" ]] //by default order by cip code
    });
```

And my 'serverSide' route that gets called looks like:

```html
Route::get('/serverSide', [
    'as'   => 'serverSide',
    'uses' => function () {
    $model = \App\Degree::query();
    return DataTables::eloquent($model)->make();
}
]);
```

The 'Degree' model is entirely empty except for defining the corresponding table to be 'degree_inventory'

The table initially populates, expands child rows, and paginates perfectly, but any query into the search bar returns the following error:
Column not found: 1054 unknown column 'degree_inventory' in 'where clause' followed by the raw query that attempts to find matches to entries in each row.
If anyone has any insight I'd be very appreciative. Thank you!

Comment: do you use package?

Comment: Where does degree_inventory come from?  Is it an appended field by chance?  It doesn't seem to exist in the database, so it must be added from somewhere.

Comment: @Devon 'degree_inventory' is a view in the database, it's in the same schema used by the rest of the application. It compiles info from a few different tables within

Comment: I don't think that's right.  If you look in your datatables raw response, I think you'll find a column named degree_inventory which is why the datatables package is trying to submit a search query on that column.

Comment: @Alihosseinshahabi it's the  common laravel datatables package https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master

Comment: @Devon, It is unusual though, because the datatable does its initial data fetch perfectly with the same table definition. Nowhere else in the application is any other table referenced, the columns in my view are: cip, cip_title, item_name, state_code_list, and degree_name_list.

Comment: That's to be expected since it's not searching any columns on the initial fetch.  The view columns don't matter, this is all backend.  The datatables package thinks your table has a degree_inventory column because that is being pulled in from somewhere.  Can't do much more to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I had a column of buttons to expand and collapse child rows.

The solution was to disable to searchable property of the expand/collapse column because the content of the column is exclusively images.

For example:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "columns": [
    { "searchable": false }, //first column is the expand button
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null
  ] } );
} );
```